# perl: upper case evaluation for subroutine

Tags: perl

I need to pass system variable in upper case to perl subroutine.

For example, if the variable with name VARNAME (value 'super'), i need to pass "SUPER_MAN".
In general, if we use 'uc' option like in the example below, we can convert to upper case

```
 perl -e 'print uc"$ENV{VARNAME}\n"'
```

But when we try to pass it in subroutine, we need to include uc function in the syntax and evaluate during runtime. To emulate that I was trying the below but not working, Where am I going wrong?

```
perl -e 'print ".uc($ENV{VARNAME})_MAN\n"'
.uc(super)_MAN
```

Alternate methods/approach is also welcome.

Comment: Can you first evaluate, `$varname = uc($ENV{VARNAME}) . '_MAN'` and pass that into subroutine? You should be able to do it in the call itself, too, `func(uc(...) . '_MAN')`.  And, as [xxfelixxx](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1799189/xxfelixxx) showed you, `uc` cannot be inside double quotes just so.

Answer (score 3):

Take the `uc` out of the quotes `""`, since perl thinks you want the literal letters `uc`:

```
FOO=abc perl -e 'print "." . uc($ENV{FOO}) . "_MAN\n"'
.ABC_MAN
```

[perldoc perlop - Quote and Quote like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)